# Changing File Path When Reading an Excel Document

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to open an excel sheet using Pandas. I have multiple documents all named the same thing, but located in different directories. Up until now, I've been using

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('C:\filepath\Neon_Source.xlsx', sheetname='Neon_Source')
Time = df['Time (s)']
Voltage = df['C2 DC (V)']
```

When I have the code in the same file, it runs smoothly. But, when I add a file path to it, it gives me the following error:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 7-8: malformed \N character escape

I'd like to keep my code saved in one place while opening excel sheets from any directory.

Thanks!

Comment: `\ ` is an escape character for a string. You need to escape it to have a working path: 'C:\\filepath\\Neon_Source.xlsx'

Comment: @ASGM, I copied the file directory directly from windows explorer, I'm using the full file path.

Comment: @JeanRostan, I changed it too: `df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Trial 8\\Neon_Source.xlsx', sheetname='Neon_Source')
`, but it's now giving me the error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\Trial 8\\Neon_Source.xlsx'"

Comment: The error seems pretty clear, make sure your path is correct. The returning error is not Python related.